# How to determine disk space used by an Indexed view in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to determine how much disk space is used by an Indexed/Materialized View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx)

> Displays the number of rows, disk
>   space reserved, and disk space used by
>   a table, indexed view, or Service
>   Broker queue in the current database,
>   or displays the disk space reserved
>   and used by the whole database.